# Adding multiple array items to a global array from a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, scope

/* Issue 1: It seems I'm having an issue with regards to scope.  My goal is to push a prompted response into the array, without keeping the variables within the function, scope is preventing the variables from communicating (or at least as it seems.) This also prevents getElementById from showing as a constant without being called by the function.

Issue 2: When the variables are all placed locally, the prompt replaces it's previous item in the array, making it only one item that can be added,  wondering if anyone has suggestions on how to add more and more.

HTML:

```
<p id = "coding"></p>
<button onclick="addTo()">Add</button>
New Quality
<br><br>
<button onclick="noMas()">Delete</button>
Remove Quality
```

JS:

```
function addTo(){
var progQual = ["Creative"," "+"Original"+" "+"Innovative", ];
addQuality = prompt("Add Another Quality");
addQuality = progQual.push(" "+addQuality);
document.getElementById("coding").innerHTML = progQual;

function noMas(){progQual.shift(progQual);}
};
```

kinda stumped at this point :(

Answer (score 0):

First assign ids to your buttons and remove onclick attributes:

```
<p id = "coding"></p>
<button id="btn-add">Add</button>
New Quality
<br><br>
<button id="btn-delete">Delete</button>
Remove Quality
```

In your JS isolate your code in an self-invoking anonymos function and define progEqual in parent scope of callbacks. Use  [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add listeneres.:

```
(function() { //Isolate scope
  /*
   * Define array in parent scope of callbacks to gain access to 
   * same referemce in both callbacks
   */
  var progQual = ["Creative"," "+"Original"+" "+"Innovative"];

  document.getElementById("btn-add").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Add logic
  });

  document.getElementById("btn-delete").addEventListener("click", function() {
    //Delete logic
  });

}());
```

For more information just search for Javascript Scopes for example this tutorial from [Scotch.io - Understanding Javascript Scope](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-scope-in-javascript).